# Multiple records with min function

Tags: sql

```
select distinct SD.RefNo,  MIN(Datefrom) E_DateFrom ,EmploymentStatusID 
from StudentEmploymentHistory SEH
RIGHT JOIN SDetail SD ON SD. StudentID  = SEH.StudentID
```

I want to be able to get result as just one record but because the Employmentstatus has multiple records, I now have more than one record

My result, only need the record with the Min Datefrom

[image: 1]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to get than `optional data right join main table`.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select sd.RefNo,  seh.E_DateFrom, seh.EmploymentStatusID 
from SDetail sd left join
     (select seh.*,
             row_number() over (partition by seh.StudentID order by Datefrom) as seqnum
      from StudentEmploymentHistory SEH
     ) seh
    on seh.StudentID = sd.StudentID and seh.seqnm = 1;
```